# Flutter Realm Error: Property type ObjectId not supported

Tags: database, mongodb, flutter, realm, mongo-dart

I'm trying to query my MongoDB database based on the primary key, which is `_id` and of type `ObjectId`.

I get the error:

```
The following RealmException was thrown building Builder:
Property type ObjectId not supported
```

when using the code:

```
ObjectId id = ObjectId.parse(retrievedId); //retrievedId is a String in the form of an ObjectId
var userData = realmServices.realm.query<UserSchema>(r"_id == $0", [id]);
```

I tried serializing with BSON but it kept giving me the same error. Also, using the query like:

```
String query = "_id == oid($id)";
var userData = realmServices.realm.query<UserSchema>(query);
```

but these solutions didn't work either, the query one giving me a `Invalid  syntax` error.

What should I do?

EDIT

As suggested by @Jay, I tried implementing the 'find' method, which queries by primary key.

Using the code:

```
ObjectId id = ObjectId.parse(retrievedId);
print(id); //this looks like 'ObjectId("someobjectidhere")'
var userData = realmServices.realm.find<UserSchema>(id);
```

I manage to get the same error:

```
The following RealmException was thrown building Builder:
Property type ObjectId not supported
```

which points directly to this line:
`var userData = realmServices.realm.find<UserSchema>(id);`

If `id` is converted to `String` instead of `ObjectId`, the error disappears, but, the queried data is always `null`.

So here comes my question, what am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: What's being attempted is unclear. In flutter, to fetch an object by the objects ID, this is the correct syntax `final someObject = realm.find<SomeRealmClass>(objectPrimaryKey);`. In other words, if you know the primary key, there's no reason to query because the object can be read directly. It may be helpful to review the Realm Flutter Getting Started Guide [Read and Write](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/realm-database/read-and-write-data/#find-object-by-primary-key)

Comment: @Jay Getting the same error, passing the ObjectId as String returns me no data and passing it as ObjectId gives me the error from the post. Any ideas?
This is the code I used: 
`var userData = realmServices.realm.find<UserSchema>(id);`

Comment: I think we can help but the question itself needs updating. Please edit the question to include the actual code you're using - ensuring it matches the example code in the Realm Getting started guide. We need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which includes defining what `id` resolves to. Update it and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay take a look at the new edit, you might be able to help me somehow?

Comment: Did you try `var userData = realmServices.realm.find<UserSchema>(retrievedId);`?

Comment: Yes, it returns 'null', as if the user is non-existent in the database.

Comment: Did you visually verify the retrievedId matches what's actually stored in that Realm Objects PrimaryKey? You may be able to Realm Studio to investigate.